# Access Violation Mystery with gethostbyname?

Tags: c++

```
std::cout << WebClient().Load(in.substr(2, in.length()));
```

I made a WebClient for fun, and you can pass in a string through cin to in via std::getline(cin, in);

The starting part of my Load method:

```
std::string Load(std::string url)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        return "WSAStartup failed.\n";
    }
    SOCKET Socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    struct hostent *host;
    host = gethostbyname(url.c_str());
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port=htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    if(host != nullptr)
    {
        SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
    }
```

I would get an Access Violation because host becomes a nullptr (hence checking it), yet with the same string but passed in differently: WebClient().Load("www.google.ca") it works. and I tried putting c_str() at the end of the substr'ed string with no avail.

I am still learning the quirks, what's up with this? I am using standard libraries from

```
#include <http.h>
#include <string>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
```

Comment: @hyde I was looking at the parameter var in debug mode and it was "www.google.ca", the same as passing it in as a const string

Comment: So, `gethostbyname` returns nullptr, you say? What do you pass to it in that case, what is value of url?

Comment: Well when gethostbyname returns nullptr the string retrieved by getline() is passed into the method. It doesn't return nullptr if it is a const string, yet even in debug mode it seems non-malformed and gethostbyname cannot handle it?

Comment: So you are saying, for *identical* calls to gethostbyname, you sometimes get address, sometimes nullptr? If unsure, add debug print before gethostbyname.

Comment: Also, check gethostbyname error: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: So is the question about an access violation or about why `gethostbyname()` returns a null pointer?  What does `WSAGetLastError()` return in that case? Print `url.c_str()` to the console when you get the error to make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: For seemingly identical parameters, I always get a proper pointer for the const literal string, and I never get a proper pointer for the cin string. I get WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND11001, hmm, what is the difference between "www.google.ca" from literal to cin?

Comment: @RobertGawdzik: dump the length of the strings and the hex values of contents of the strings - there is something different about them. Keep in mind that sometimes the debugger display of strings might not show things like control characters well - if at all, so don't depend on that. If you're looking at the data only in the debugger, use the raw memory view to look at the memory dump of the string data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing my comments as an answer: You should print the URL in a way which lets you see if there are extra chars, even whitespace. Then you should check error codes of all functions you use, like here read [the documentation of `gethostbyname`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) through. A debug version of your function below, and with that you need the [error codes explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#include <cstring>

std::string Load(std::string url)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        return "WSAStartup failed.\n";
    }
    SOCKET Socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    struct hostent *host;
    std::cout << "Getting hostname for url as seen by gethostbyname: '" << url.c_str() << "', strlen=" << strlen(url.c_str()) << std::endl;
    host = gethostbyname(url.c_str());
    if (host) {
        std::cout << "got valid hostent as response" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "gethostbyname WSAGetLastError=" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        return "Invalid url.\n";
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port=htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    if(host != nullptr)
    {
        SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
    }
```

A guess of a reason: your url from `cin` has whitespace in it.

A note on terminology: that address string, it is not really url, url must have scheme like `http://` at the start. What you have there is a *fully qualified domain name* of the host, as it should be too, `gethostbyname` does not understand urls.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking what the value of the passed in string is received as from `getline`. It could be malformed when `gethostbyname` receives it. You can check if this is where it's failing (and becoming NULL) by using [`WSAGetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Check MSDN for `gethostbyname`'s possible [error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**EDIT**: You say you have seemingly identical parameters. Can you find a way to prove this (to yourself). Maybe there are invisible characters that got in there? A new line `\n`, or perhaps it uses a different encoding? Just some ideas.